# Do legendaries respawn after defeating them?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

If I kill a legendary in ORAS that I find in a mirage spot will it respawn?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will respawn if you re-beat the Elite 4. That is the case for all legendaries, except Rayquaza (but you had to capture that one anyway).